# Delphi Prism - how do I determine actual class that TObjectExtender is "extending"

Tags: delphi-prism, oxygene, delphi-prism-2010

I have a large quantity of logging throughout my Delphi code, which often uses Self.ClassName to log the name of the class containing the currently executing code.

I am now compiling some of this code into a Delphi Prism .NET assembly.

However, under Delphi Prism, Self.ClassName now returns "TObjectExtender" instead of the actual classname.

e.g.

```
type
  TMyClass: TObject
  begin
    procedure MyProc();
  end;
...

procedure TMyClass.MyProc;
begin
  Log(Format('%s: A log message', [Self.ClassName]));
end;
```

outputs

```
TMyClass: A log message
```

when compiled in Delphi XEII, but when compiled in Delphi Prism in VS 2010 outputs

```
TObjectExtender: A log message
```

regardless of the actual class containing the running code.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the actual classname in Delphi Prism please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of current class just use

```
Self.GetType().Name
```